# Java - sort a static array in the declaration line (instead of in a static constructor)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, static

**I have a class with a large static array of integers:**

```
private static int[] array = {...};
```

I want to have it sorted without adding a static constructor, where I would call `Arrays.sort(array)`.

On Python, I could simply write `array = sorted([...])`.

**Questions:**

1. Is there any similar routine in Java, that I can use in a similar manner?
2. Is there any other way for me to have the array sorted in the declaration line?

P.S.: It would also allow me to declare it `final`, which I would not be able to do otherwise.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question: you want it to be sorted, but do not want to use Arrays.sort()?

Comment: If to translate the question to Python, I want to use `array = sorted([x,y,z])` instead of `list = [x,y,z]` and then `array = list.sort()`. In other words, my problem with `Arrays.sort` is that it does not return an array.

Comment: Can I edit your question to replace static constructor with static *initialiser*?

Comment: Yes, thank you (didn't know that this was the terminology for it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
private static final int[] array = mySort(new int[]{...})

private static int[] mySort(int[] a) {
    Arrays.sort(a);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: But after trying it out, should change from `mySort({...})` to `mySort(new int[]{...})` in order to compile.

Answer (score 5):

You **can** declare it `final` and **still** use a static initialiser:

```
private static final int[] array;

static {
    array = {...};
    Arrays.sort(array);
}
```

Comment: In fact you don't even have to use a local_array. Even though the array is declared final the actual contents of the array can still be modified, meaning you can call `Arrays.sort(array)` even after it has been assigned.

Answer (score 4):

If you insist on avoiding static blocks/methods to no real benefit:

```
  private static final int[] foo = new Callable<int[]>() {
    public int[] call() {
      int[] arr = { 3, 2, 1 };
      Arrays.sort(arr);
      return arr;
    }
  }.call();
```

On the off-chance you're on Java 8:

```
private static final int[] foo = IntStream.of(3, 2, 1)
                                          .sorted()
                                          .toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Close to Ingo's solution, but I'd want to make `sorted` non-destructive:

```
public static int[] sorted(int [] arr) {
   int[] copy = new int[arr.length];
   System.arraycopy(arr, 0, copy, 0, arr.length);
   Arrays.sort(copy);
   return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing something. You need to call a method at runtime to sort it, the compiler won't do it for you. But what exactly is the problem with:

```
final static int[] array = sorted( new int[] { ..... } );
```

which is quite the same as in Python. You just need a static method:

```
public static int[] sorted(int [] arr) {
    Array.sort(arr);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: `Array.sort()`  is a `void` method :)

Comment: You could've found the workaround, @barakmanos, couldn't you?

Comment: Well... funny how sometimes the simple things elude you (elude me, in this specific case)... but if memory serves correctly, you initially suggested `array = Array.sort({...})`, which doesn't quite work either... so I guess it kinda eluded us both, right?

Comment: Sure, because I couldn't imagine the API is *thus stupid*. Hence, in reaction to the compiler message, I'd written `sorted`.